# How to validate client side obtained token with dexie cloud from our server

Tags: dexie, dexie-cloud

After user logs in to Dexie Cloud first time, we would want to create a customer with Stripe. How can our backend validate a Dexie Cloud user token for authenticity when receiving a request to check or create a Stripe customer, assuming the request is initiated after a user successfully logs in and db.cloud.currentUser is available?

I can't seem to find any documentation how to verify the user token in requests made with dexie cloud token from our client app to our backend servers.